# PyScripter with multiple version of Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, operating-system, pyscripter

I've recently installed Python 3.3 in addition Python 2.7 on my Computer (Windows 7, 32-bit). Python 3.3 gives you the possibility of adding a "shebang line" at top of your .py files so when you execute them it can select which Python version to use. Since Pyscripter doesn't recognise this "shebang lines", i wrote a programm which reads the first line of a .py file and then opens it in Pyscripter with the correspondent Argument.
It looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
from sys import argv
from os import system
if len(argv)>1:
    file = open(argv[1])
    shebang=file.readline()
    if shebang.split()[1] in {'python2','python2.7'}:
        system(r'C:\Python27\PyScripter.exe --python27 "'+argv[1]+'"')
    elif shebang.split()[1] in {'python3','python3.3'}:
        system(r'C:\Python33\PyScripter.exe --python33 "'+argv[1]+'"')
else:
    system(r'C:\Python27\PyScripter.exe --python27')
file.close()
exit()
```

I then compiled the program using py2exe and selected is as standard operation for .py files. When I open a .py file now, PyScripter opens the file using the correct version of python, but when i try to save the file it says:

```
Error saving file: "C:\Users\...\Python\example.py".
Error: Cannot create file "C:\Users\...\Python\example.py". The process cannot acces the file because it is being used by another process
```

The compiled program for opening PyScripter is still running, but even if i kill it it still brings that message. Same thing happens with a cmd.exe window opened by the program. If i try to delete/rename/move the file in Windows Explorer it say i can't do it, because the file is currently being used by PyScripter.exe.
Does anybody know how to solve this?

The program to open PyScripter is Python 2.7, since i don#t have py2exe for Python 3.

Comment: Try using the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead of `system()` to launch `PyScripter.exe`.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` worked, thanks